# PHP Facebook SDK object slow to instantiate

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

My script runs quickly on one machine and very slowly on another. I've narrowed the sticking point to this line:

```
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
```

What ways can I further debug this? Is my only option to open the SDK and start adding echos so I can identify the sticking point within the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already got the solution of this problem but I just want to add answer to help others. 
This problem is because php session_start() is painfully slow([http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/123301-session-start-is-slow/](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/123301-session-start-is-slow)) which is getting called when you make object of facebook class.

The solution might be using database based sessions(http://jameshalsall.co.uk/php-database-sessions/) and/or including session_write_close() at the end of __construct method.